# Button in a different file than the main

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I have 2 button but they need to be in a different file than the mainWindow.cs.
I can't figure how to do that.

So the `Button_Click_2` must be in the `ReadData.cs` and the
`Button_Click_3` must be in the `WriteData.cs`

The app don't recognize the button when they are not in the mainWindow.
How can I do that ?

ReadData.cs :

```
public new void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = verifyCard("5"); // 5 - is the block we are reading
        textBlock1.Text = text.ToString();
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs :

```
public void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //When I click it don't detected the code in the ReadData.cs
        // The code of the button must be in the ReadData.cs
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml :

```
 <Grid>
    <Button Content="Connexion" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 Margin="265,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="236" Height="44" 
 Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <Button  Content="Lire donnée carte" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 Margin="265,276,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="236" Height="42" 
 Click="Button_Click_2"/>
    <Button Content="Ecrire donnée carte" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 Margin="265,344,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="236" Height="41" 
 Click="Button_Click_3"/>
    <TextBox Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" 
 Margin="321,224,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
    <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 Margin="291,95,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
 Height="23" Width="177"/>

</Grid>
```

It must be possible to forced the app to detected and execute the code in another file than the Main.

I'm stuck... do any of you have the solution ?

Comment: If i understand properly u placed this code `public new void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = verifyCard("5"); // 5 - is the block we are reading
        textBlock1.Text = text.ToString();
    }` in ReadData.cs and pressing the button the its not working

Comment: if u place the `button_Click_2` code in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` its working fine

Comment: yes but i need to execute this button outisde the mainWindow.cs.

Comment: "*The code of the button must be in the ReadData.cs*" - that is totally wrong. You are talking about a Button Click event handler method that is used in MainWindow.xaml. The method must therefore be declared in the MainWindow class, i.e. in MainWindow.xaml.cs. What you actually need is an object reference to an instance of your ReadData class to call its methods or set its properties. Or you call static methods of the ReadData class without an object reference.

Comment: Yes, When i click the button it need to acces to the ReadData.cs and excute the code.

Comment: The event handlers *must* be defined in the same class for you to be able to hook up them in the XAML markup. So you can't move the actual `Button_Click_2` out of the code-behind. You can however move the actual logic to another method of another class and then simply call this method from the event handler.

Comment: If I put the code of the button in the main, I will have error because of the private property of the 'verifyCard()'

Comment: @– mm8 do you have an example to how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just place the button code in  ReadData.cs class. as the event is related to ui of `MainWindow.xaml` create an object for ReadData do something like this

```
 public new void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    ReadData rd= new ReadData();
    string text = rd.verifyCard("5"); 
    textBlock1.Text = text.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, it work. I tried in another file because of this : https://www.iranthajayasekara.com/blog/read-and-write-to-nfc-card-with-acr122u-reader.html

Comment: The button are not in the main that why.